# Are the <References> and <Imports> tags supposed to work for C# code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

Microsoft has conflicting documentation for custom code snippets. According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2017#add-references-and-imports):

> You can add a reference to a project by using the References element, and add an Imports declaration by using the Imports element. (**This works for C# as well.**)

But then, [the schema reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets-schema-reference?view=vs-2017#imports-element) contradicts that and says:

> The Imports element is only supported for Visual Basic projects.

I'm currently trying to use the `<References>` and `<Imports>` elements for a C# snippet, and it works with the shortcut, but it does not add the `using` statements or references.

Here is the XML for the `.snippet` file that I'm testing with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Test snippet</Title>
      <Author>Test Author</Author>
      <Description>Test Description</Description>
      <Shortcut>test1</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Windows.Forms.dll</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Drawing.dll</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <Imports>
      <Import>
        <Namespace>System.Windows.Forms</Namespace>
      </Import>
      <Import>
        <Namespace>System.Drawing</Namespace>
      </Import>
    </Imports>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Are `<References>` and `<Imports>` really supported by C#? Or is it only supported by Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0):

It does work for C# as well, you just have to put the References and Imports inside of the `<Snippet></Snippet>`.

Example:

```
<Snippet>
        <References>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System.dll</Assembly>
            </Reference>
        </References>
        <Imports>
            <Import>
            <Namespace>System.ComponentModel</Namespace>
            </Import>
        </Imports>
        <Code Language="CSharp">
            <![CDATA[
            
            
            ]]>
        </Code>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>ModelClass</ID>
                <Default>object</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
    </Snippet>
```

Read more here: [msdn Walkthrough on Code Snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019)